# Font problem, TEXMFHOME

Tags: texlive, installing, environment-variables, kpathsea, kpsewhich

I have a brand new TeXLive vanilla installation on my Debian system. Before installing it I had removed all Debian TeX packages. The `texmf.cnf`in the installation only contains comments, I did not touch it.

When I pdftex a certain document, TeX starts generating fresh font files as it should and places them into `/home/username/.texlive2021` However `kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME` reports `/home/username/texmf` The user has no `TEXMFHOME` set.

**Problem 1:** I was expecting the fonts to show up on `/home/username/texmf` due to the `kpsewhich` result. Is my expectation wrong? Where does the used location `HOME/.texlive2021` come from, where/who specified the string `.texlive2021`?

**Problem 2:** I have a PHP application connecting pdftex to a server interface. A client makes a `GET` on the PHP endpoint and PHP starts pdftex. Now pdftex *fails* to start the font generation on its own but produces a `missfont.log` file in the current working directory of the pdftex process. **Why** does pdftex fail to start the font generation in the PHP setting while it works in the manual bash setting. The process environment knows `PATH`, `TEXMFHOME` and `HOME` variables. **What else** is missing here?

**Problem 3:** When I now manually execute the font commands in `missfont.log` the fonts are constructed in `/home/username/.texlive2021` as described above under problem 1. When I then use the PHP server endpoint again, pdftex now **ignores** the `TEXMFHOME` environment variable but picks up the `HOME` environment variable, appends a `.texlive2021` and finds the fonts from the earlier manual run. **Why** would pdftex ignore the `TEXMFHOME`setting? How can I specify this if not in `TEXMFHOME`?

**Conclusion:** I need to get the font construction process running automagically for the PHP service. My access to various error messages is a bit limited in the remote/server/PHP setting, which is why I compare with manual process starting. However the shell started processes (1) behave different than I believe they should (problems 1 and 3) and (2) behave different than the process PHP runs via the exec call (problem 2).

**Postscriptum:** The core problem was that PHP did not provide the *complete* environment. First it lacked the variables, Ulrike Fischer pointed out. Second it lacked the path to further Linux tools which are needed in the font generation process.

Comment: regarding 1.: automatically generated stuff is placed into texmfvar and texmfsysvar.

Comment: COOL. Helped me solve 2 and 3 as well. I ran the installer again and realized that I overlooked the choice I can make there. Not knowing about these two env variables I did not set them in the PHP environment. pdftex **did** start the font generation but mktexpk needs sed. sed was not in the path since I gave PHP only a path to latex & co to separate Linux Tex from vanilla TUG Tex installation. I did not get that part of the error message in the .log, as pdftex has no access to it and, of course, also did not redirect stderr for PHP. Saw the error in the shell and now everything works.

Comment: Was really helpful. Can I somehow help you to some SE points? You only gave that as comment and more than upvote that here I cannot do. But if you write an answer I can accept the answer. Definitely helped me solve my issues and taught me a lot more. **THNX**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding your first question:

automatically generated stuff is placed into `texmfvar` and `texmfsysvar` not `texmfhome`.